# Change the height of md-nav-item in angular material

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

Please how can I override the default height of `md-nav-item` in angular material using CSS. I have the following sample code:

```
 <div ng-cloak>
<md-content class="md-padding">
  <md-nav-bar
  md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem"
  nav-bar-aria-label="navigation links">
    <md-nav-item name="Page1" md-nav-click="goto('page2')">
      Link1
    </md-nav-item>
    <md-nav-item name="Page2" md-nav-click="goto('page2')">
      Link2
    </md-nav-item>
    <md-nav-item name="Page3" md-nav-click="goto('page2')">
      Link3
    </md-nav-item>
  </md-nav-bar>
  <div class="ext-content">
    {{currentNavItem}}
  </div>
</md-content>
```

See also example on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4tbxH45Nuum2vIS6oIHB?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

After inspecting the styles, you can do something like this to change the height of the nabvar:

<kbd>[PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/oaUhyaCEtBbmirjhDRFk?p=preview)</kbd> *(Work from angular-material version >= 1.1.0)*

```
.md-nav-bar, .md-nav-bar > nav, ._md-nav-bar-list, .md-button._md-nav-button{
  height: 50px;
}

.md-button._md-nav-button {
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 0;
}
```

**** *Be sure of include your `styles.css` file after the `angular-material.css` file in your `index.html`*

---

**Explanation:** You're asking about change the height of `md-nav-item`, but in fact, this directive is writing/transcluding a `ul._md-nav-bar-list` with `.md-button._md-nav-button` inside each `li`. So, you have to change the height of `.md-button._md-nav-button`. But the problem is that buttons doesn't have height, they have padding and min-height. 
And even, the main problem is that `.md-nav-bar` has a default height (48px), so if you change the height of items inside it, it doens't matter, you have to override this default height first.

Comment: Lovely...this solved my problem and saved me the trouble of battling with CSS for hours.

Comment: @FrederickEze Mark this as the correct answer then!